# Errors ajax Error: Message->200 - >SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character->[object Object]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, zend-framework

This is my code work with zendFramwork1.2

```
$("#cboCateMain1").change(function(){
var id=$(this).val();
var dataString = 'catmainid='+ id;      
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<?php echo $this->baseUrl ();?>/<?php echo $this->translate('lang')?>/<?php echo $this->controller?>/catemainindex",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: function() {                 
    },
    timeout: 1000000,
    error:function(xhr, status, error) { 
        alert('Error: Message->'+ xhr.status+ ' - >'+ error+"->"+xhr);
     },
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    } 
});
});
```

but i got errors like !

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmgok.jpg)

Any idea with problem! I am looking for your reply soon. Thanks

Comment: What does the PHP code that handles the request look like?

Answer (score 0):

That means something is wrong with your returned json data. First try to return a hard coded json string to this request. [Here](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) is a very good site to validate your json